# Hi, I have a JSF page with a menubar. I would like to show a message at the top of the page to display the result of an action from a dialog box

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I would like to show a message (p:message) at the top of a JSF page as a result of an action from a dialog. 
I am trying to write to a database through a dialog box and would like to display the message on the JSF page (NOT on the dialog box) a message that the action was successful or not.

I am using primefaces 6.2.2.

I tried using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance.addMessage("null",newFacesMessage...) but it does not display anything on the JSF page

Here are the list of files and a quick overview of each file:
Thanks!

dialog.xhtml: This is the main xhtml file on which I would like to show the messages at the top. This contains a menubar as you can see below with in a  tag. It calls the menubar.model in menubar.java shown below

```
<body>
    <h:form id="formId">
        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" closable="true"
            globalOnly="true">
            <p:autoUpdate />
        </p:messages>
    </h:form>
    <h3>Dialog Sample</h3>
    <h:form>
        <p:menubar model="#{menuBar.model}" style="margin: auto;" />
    </h:form>
</body>
```

dialogForm.xhtml: this is the dialog box with an input text to enter the "name". I would like to show a message on dialog.xhtml when the user clicks the button referenced by p:commandButton which calls dialogParams.submit

```
<body>
    <h:form>
        <p:outputLabel value="Dialog Sample" />
        <br />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Portfolio Name" />
            <p:inputText value="#{dialogParams.name}" id="portfolioName" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <br />
        <p:commandButton action="#{dialogParams.submit}" value="Submit" />
    </h:form>
</body>
```

menuActions.java: This is called from menubar.java when the user selects the "Create Portfolio" from the menubar. This shows the dialog form (dialogForm.xhtml)

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MenuActions implements Serializable {

    public void createPortfolio(ActionEvent ae) {
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.put("resizable", false);
        options.put("draggable", false);
        options.put("modal", true);
        PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("dialogForm", options, null);
        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Successfully completed"));
    }
}
```

DialogParams.java: This will execute the action (I have removed the database actions for simplicity). I am calling the FacesContext.getCurrentInstace... to show the message after closing the dialog.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class DialogParams implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    public void submit() {
        PrimeFaces.current().dialog().closeDynamic(null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("formId", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", this.getName()));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

menubar.java

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MenuBar implements Serializable {
private MenuModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();


        DefaultSubMenu submenu = new DefaultSubMenu();
        submenu.setLabel("Create");
        submenu.setIcon("pi pi-plus");

        DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
        item.setValue("Portfolio");
        item.setCommand("#{menuActions.createPortfolio}");

        //item.setCommand("#{}");
        submenu.addElement(item);
        model.addElement(submenu);

        submenu = new DefaultSubMenu();
        submenu.setLabel("Update");
        submenu.setIcon("pi pi-pencil");
        model.addElement(submenu);

        submenu = new DefaultSubMenu();
        submenu.setLabel("View");
        submenu.setIcon("pi pi-eye");
        model.addElement(submenu);
    }

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(MenuModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your dialog.xhtml an own page because I see a body tag there? If yes then no wonder you see nothing on the main page because it is another view and the current view state is related to your dialog page during the request and not the main page. So messages must be displayed on dialog page and cannot be displayed on another page, they are not the same view. Why not using p:dialog for a dialog on the main page? Another thing is that p:messages should not need a form tag because its no input field an you cannot submit anything with it.

Comment: Thomas, yes it is a main page. Thanks for your suggestion. I implemented a p:dialog which worked.